# Google Script Won't Display

Tags: google-apps-script

New to Google Scripting but not new to Object-oriented programming. Just completed a Google Script that appears properly when I click on "Test Web App for you latest code" after publishing the script. However when I go to the URL provided, nothing shows on the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: For those who don't know what "OO programming" is (changed to "Object-oriented programming")

Comment: It should work the same at both urls, but obviously little details can get in the way.  You'll need to post the relevant code and a screenshot of your deployment settings on the "publish as web-app" window wouldn't hurt either, otherwise we can only guess.  Note - this sounds like a Google Apps Script question, not an App Engine question, correct me if I'm wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

For publishing scripts you need ti activate the versioning
Did you register the version?
First menu/. Manage versions/ enter version description and save it